# Symfony2 doctrine flushing multiple objects and ignoring only ones which throws exception

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm doing data import. and I want to do flush every 1000 rows or so. The problem is when I try to import something with invalid data and I get Exception and none of the entries are flushed. How do I make it to flush all entries except the one which throws exception? Also it would be nice to get count how many insertions/updates where successful and how many failed

Comment: What's your actually code ? To import 1000 rows ? Maybe in foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine2 is not recommanded to do mass data export/import.

> An ORM tool is not primarily well-suited for mass inserts, updates or deletions.
>   http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

It's safer to use DBAL connection to do the sql queries.

If the exception is thrown because of invalid data, it makes sense to validate the data before persisting your entity